# Ninject how to resolve dependency in one call

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm new to Ninject, after do some research, I came up with an example:

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    void Hit(Target target);
}

public class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(Target target)
    {
        //do something here
    }
}

public class Character
{
    private IWeapon weapon;

    public Character(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    public void Attack(Target target)
    {
        this.weapon.Hit(target);
    }
}

public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public overrides void Load()
    {
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    Target sometarget = new Target();
    Kernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new Bindings());
    var weapon = kernel.Get<IWeapon>();
    var character = new Character(weapon);
    character.Attack(sometarget);
}
```

As you can see, in order to resolve the dependency, I have to pull instance of `IWeapon` using `Kernel` and pass it to `Character`'s constructor. I think this somehow ugly, I wonder is there a way that I can directly pull instance of `Character` and Ninject will automatically resolve the dependency with `IWeapon`? Something like:

```
Character character = kernel.Resolve<Character>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Ninject will allow you to auto resolve concrete types with the correct bindings. In you instance you could just do:

```
public void Main()
{
    Target sometarget = new Target();
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new Bindings());
    //var weapon = kernel.Get<IWeapon>();
    var character = kernel.Get<Character>();
    character.Attack(sometarget);
}
```

For more information read through the Ninject wiki: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject

Answer (score 1):

You haven't registered Character.  Create an ICharacter interface and Bind it to the Character class as well.  Then when you attempt to resolve the ICharacter, Ninject will see that it needs an instance of IWeapon for the Character constructor and it will get one that is registered to that interface.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But @Gary. S's answer is more suit my intention so I can only give you an upvote.